# Combining Tkinter Widgets Into Single Class Limits Accessibility?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I am working on a project that involves creating many instances of Tkinter Labels and Entry widgets that will always be aligned next to one another. To try and save myself time, I created a custom class that I am showing below:

```
 class labelEntry(Label,Entry):
  def __init__(self,parent,label,row,column,bg_color):
    Label.__init__(self,parent)
    self['text']=label
    self['justify']='right'
    self['bg']=bg_color
    self.grid(row=row,column=column, sticky=E)


    Entry.__init__(self,parent)
    self['width']="10"
    self.grid(row=row,column=column+1)
```

This creates the configuration I want and is easy enough to arrange (I have them stored in a frame). The problem is I don't know how to access the Entry widgets that I have created as they are part of this new class.

I have a desire to read and delete the entries from the entry widgets. My best guess at clearing them was with this button that was being fed into the same frame:

```
class clearAllEntry(Button):
def clearAll(self,targetFrame):
    targetFrame.labelEntry.Entry.delete(0,END)

def __init__(self,parent,targetFrame):
    Button.__init__(self,parent,text='Clear All Entries',bg='black',fg='white')
    self['command']= "clearAll(targetFrame)"
```

I have also looked at grid_slave as an approach but am having the same issue.
Any advice/help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

First off, if you're creating a new class that contains two objects of different classes, you should not be using inheritance. Instead, use composition.

Second, to be able to access the entry widget, save it to an instance variable.

For example:

```
class LabelEntry():
    def __init__(self, parent, label, row, column, bg_color):

        self.label = Label(parent, text=label, justify='right', bg=bg_color)
        self.entry = Entry(parent, width=10)

        self.label.grid(row=row, column=column, sticky="e")
        self.grid(row=row,column=column+1)
```

Later, you can reference these attributes like you can any other attribute:

```
le1 = LabelEntry(root)
...
print(le1.entry.get())
```